# Testing Camel REST DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to test a Camel route. The route uses the REST DSL to receive `POST` requests, conduct some processing, and return a value.

My tests are returning odd messages bodies and I'm not sure why.

Here is the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    public void newRequest() throws IOException {
        // Then call the REST API

        // Read file as a string into a variable 'content'
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test_data.csv")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // Create a rest template to create a (post) request
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Create Mulipart-form data and set the content type to multpart-form data
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        // Create an object called 'body' of type multipart
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        // Set content (of loaded file) into the multipart object
        body.add("file", content);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8081/";

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

The response entity body value is with response status code 200:

```
{
  "--_Q_XsVubda334izooe8NkhJMiv11hjg3kHE": "--_Q_XsVubda334izooe8NkhJMiv11hjg3kHE--"
}
```

I am expecting a JSON with legible key value pairs.

I would appreciate some tips on why I'm getting this response and if i've gone wrong anywhere in my test.

Comment: `content` should be instance of `Resource`. Try with `body.add("file", new FileSystemResource(Paths.get("test_data.csv")))`

Comment: Thanks @Bedla! Still getting the same result... Any other ideas? :)

Comment: I see no more problems in test. Are you sure the issue is in test and application code is correct? You can test it by adding `Thread.sleep` to test method and then try to call the endpoint with Postman.

Comment: Yes this is what is puzzling me! Yes I am sure, I'm using Postman to check the route is returning results, which it is. Interestingly enough when I run the debugger it doesn't appear to activate any steps within the route...